# ManyToMany relationship to the same table

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, coolstorage

I'm trying to add relationship between to categories in the same table. I have a

> CATEGORIES (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT)

table and

> CATEGORIES_CATEGORIES (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>   CATEGORIES_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, SUBCATEGORIES_ID INTEGER NOT NULL)

table.

And I'm trying to map them together with Vici Coolstorage ORM. I've made classes

**Category class**

```
[MapTo("CATEGORIES")]
    public abstract class Category : CSObject<Category>
    {
        public abstract int Id { get; }
        public abstract string Name { get; set; }

        [ManyToMany("CATEGORIES_CATEGORIES", Pure = true)]
        public abstract CSList<CategoryCategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    }
```

**CategoryCategory class**

```
[MapTo("CATEGORIES_CATEGORIES")]
    public abstract class CategoryCategory : CSObject<CategoryCategory>
    {
        public abstract int Id { get; }

        [ManyToOne(LocalKey = "CATEGORIES_ID", ForeignKey = "ID")]
        public abstract Category Cat { get; set; }
        [ManyToOne(LocalKey = "SUBCATEGORIES_ID", ForeignKey = "ID")]
        public abstract Category SubCat { get; set; }
    }
```

But I cannot make it work. Can anyone help me to get this relation to work?

Comment: What does not work. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping table should not be the target of a many-to-many relation.

Try something like this:

```
[ManyToMany("CATEGORIES_CATEGORIES", 
            LocalKey="ID", ForeignKey="ID",  
            LocalLinkKey="CATEGORIES_ID", ForeignLinkKey="SUBCATEGORIES_ID")]
public abstract CSList<Category> Subcategories { get; }
```